# What hardware device do I need so I can connect my phone with an ethernet jack to my wireless internet

Tags: ethernet, hardware-rec, voip

I have a telephone which has an ethernet jack in the back (it uses VOIP). It will sit on the 2nd story of my house. My wireless router is on the first floor of my house.

What wireless adapters/hardware do I need (if such hardware exists), so that I can connect my phone to my network wirelessly as opposed to physically running an ethernet cable? For example, would either of the following devices do what I am looking for?

> [http://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-Universal-Ethernet-Adapter-GWU627/dp/B004UAKCS6/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1341962424&sr=8-3&keywords=wireless+ethernet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004UAKCS6)

or

> [http://www.amazon.com/Wireless-Dreambox-Network-Printer-Microsoft/dp/B005OIB6XI/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1341962424&sr=8-4&keywords=wireless+ethernet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005OIB6XI)

Please include link to a device(s) so I have an example of what kind of hardware I need.

Comment: can you tell us the model of the phone that has a RJ45 kack?

Comment: The IOGEAR should work to make the connection to your network. You'll need to use a PC to configure it.

Comment: Thank you. If you answer it I will give you the answer rep.

Answer (score 0):

You need to purchase a wireless bridge (This is what the IOgear that you have linked is). A wireless bridge will pickup your wireless connection and then output it through LAN outputs on the back. An even better idea would be to purchase a Wireless Repeater that has bridging functionality. Then you would be increasing the range of your wireless network and also accomplishing your original goal. I know for a fact that the Engenius series of repeaters also output the signal through their LAN port when in repeater mode because I have tested this feature before when installing a series of repeaters on a 3g network for someone that lives in the boondocks. Check it out here http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833168066

Comment: The IOGEAR GWU627 is not a [bridge](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/bridge). It's just a client station. You can't use it to bridge networks. It will work for him though -- he's just trying to attach a device to a network as a client, so no bridging is needed. (There are many questions on this site that ask why a network isn't working that boil down to -- Wifi doesn't let you bridge to a client.)

Answer (score 0):

Wifi to ethernet adapter will work in this case. I know that because I am using the BrosTrend wifi to ethernet adapter for a VOIP telephone too. [https://www.amazon.com/BrosTrend-600Mbps-Adapter-Wireless-WNA016/dp/B0118SPFCK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0118SPFCK) The device is located in a basement about 75' away from my router. I'm able to work and use my phone now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your phone has an Ethernet port, it's not too simple, just buy a wifi to ethernet adapter online, it can help you receive wireless wifi signals, and then send the signal to your phone through an Ethernet port On the mobile phone, I have a Brotrend brand at home, which is easy to use and has a fast signal. You can try to search for wifi to ethernet adapter on Amazon to see this brand.

Comment: OP was asking for more information about this, and already knew to buy a wifi to ethernet adapter, as their question clearly states.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1127921)